# Reflection getting dataContext and Table

Tags: c#, silverlight, reflection

I'm trying to create an app just for learing purposes.
I'd Like to dynamically save any object to the right context.
So my idea is something like this:

My businessmodel for the player is this:

```
[Table]
public class PLAYER:ISiedlerEntity
{
    [Column(CanBeNull = false, IsPrimaryKey = true, DbType = "INT NOT NULL Identity", IsDbGenerated = true, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
    public long ID { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public int GamesPlayed { get; set; }
}
```

}

The context is this:

```
public class PLAYERS:DataContext
{
    private const string CONNECTION_STRING = "isostore:/tblPLAYERs.sdf";

    public Table<PLAYER> Entities;

    public PLAYERS()
        : base(CONNECTION_STRING)
    {
    }
}
```

Do you think there is a possibility to handle the saving in one function just by passing the ISiedlerEntitiy?

My approach so far:

```
    public static bool Save(ISiedlerEntity entity)
    {
        bool result = true;
        string dcName = entity.GetType().Name + "S";
        PropertyInfo pi = CurrentApp.GetType().GetProperty(dcName);
        DataContext dc = pi.GetValue(CurrentApp) as DataContext;

        foreach (var prop in dc.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if (prop.Name == "Entities")
            {
                var t = prop.GetValue(dc);

            }
        }


        return result; 
    }
```

So far so fine, but now I need to cast the datacontext to the specified context, to access the Entities property.

Do you think this is possible so far? Or is there a easier solution?

Thanks and a good evening to everybody.

Matthias Müller